# Can I ask my friend who is a PhD student to recommend me to his supervisor?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, united-states

I have a friend who is a PhD student in a program at a major US university. He will graduate this year, and he knows me. I am trying to ask him to indirectly recommend me to his supervisor who I am interested in as well so that I can improve my odds for PhD admission, given I satisfy all requirements. Is this okay or even recommended to do if possible?

Comment: The admission is probably not decided by the supervisor.  It is usually the decision of a committee.

Comment: Yes, but at least he can have a more say in that if the student is talking to him about me, no?

Comment: I'll let other reader comment.  The committee is there to ensure quality and a student is admitted only if he/she has the potential to do excellent work.   If you CV is good, it speaks for itself.

Comment: In the U.S., in mathematics, enthusiastic support from faculty most often (not always) has a very positive effect on grad admissions outcomes.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably situation dependent.

If you have worked with your friend professionally before, they have a very strong opinion of your work, and they have an excellent relationship with their supervisor, then it is probably reasonable for your friend to recommend you. Though if your work is really this good, you would probably be competitive on your own merits in any case, and the recommendation won't make much difference.

On the other hand, if this is just someone you go fishing with, then they might not feel comfortable recommending you. Even if they did, a recommendation that says "user17071408 is my friend and they are a good fisherman" is not going to have much impact.

So, you'll have to consider all the individual factors to decide which of these cases is closer to your situation. But note that in both cases, we concluded that the recommendation did not make much difference either way. So, I wouldn't stress too much about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can ask your friend, of course, and he can recommend you to his supervisor, but I don't recommend it. The supervisor can't really do anything with the recommendation unless you are already admitted and usually only if you want to work with them.

It would be seen as improper for the supervisor to try to go around the admission committee's normal process and insert a piece of information into the process that isn't open to all students.

The committee process is broad based and well defined. Permitting "side" recommendations is improper. Supervisors are normally chosen (most fields) only after admission and usually after some coursework.

Don't do what might be perceived as improper and won't make a change.

---

Think for a second about a conversation between a professor and a colleague on the admissions committee. "My student recommends a friend of his for admission." Now replace it. "My son recommends a friend of his for admission".

If a university in the US permits such things as actionable, then you don't want to go there.

Comment: Well, supervisor-student has more professional content that parent-child, and could contain legitimate professional endorsement... The objection that this is going outside the system has more substance, in the U.S., in at least a legalistic sense, yes.

Comment: @paulgarrett, I was only pointing out that actual nepotism actually happens in some corners of the world. There have been questions here IIRC.

Comment: indeed, and this continues to corrupt grad admissions, postdocs, and tenure-track hiring (so far as I can see, in math, in the U.S.). But/and, visibly, "hiring/admissions committees" are not so much able to appraise future success, as they are able to appraise conformity to some superficial yardsticks. Some information is tainted, yes, and/but some information is good. And it is nearly impossible to make definitive rules to distinguish the two. Etc. :)